# Select Rows with Maximum Column Value group by Another Column

Tags: sql, mysql

This should be a simple question, but I can't get it to work :(

How to select rows that have the maximum column value,as group by another column?

For example,

I have the following table definition:

```
ID
Del_Index
docgroupviewid
```

The issue now is that I want to group by results by `docgroupviewid` first, and then choose one row from each `docgroupviewid` group, depending on which one has the highest `del_index`.

I tried

```
SELECT docgroupviewid, max(del_index),id FROM table
group by docgroupviewid
```

But instead of return me with the correct `id`, it returns me with the earliest `id` from the group with the same `docgroupviewid`.

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you break ties when there's 2+ del_index values matching the max value for the same docgroupviewid?

Comment: Not sure... you have any idea?

Comment: Classic example. troubled me too plenty of times!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've struggled with this many times myself and the solution is to think about your query differently.

I want each DocGroupViewID row where the Del_Index is the highest(max) for all rows with that DocGroupViewID:

```
SELECT
    T.DocGroupViewID,
    T.Del_Index,
    T.ID
FROM MyTable T
WHERE T.Del_Index = (
    SELECT MAX( T1.Del_Index ) FROM MyTable T1
    WHERE T1.DocGroupViewID = T.DocGroupViewID 
)
```

It gets more complex when more than one row can have the same `Del_Index`, since then you need some way to choose which one to show.

---

### EDIT: wanted to follow up with another option

You can use the `RANK()` or `ROW_NUMBER()` functions with a CTE to get more control over the results, as follows:

```
-- fake a source table
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Del_Index int,
    DocGroupViewID int
)

INSERT INTO @t
SELECT 1, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 3

-- show our source
SELECT * FROM @t

-- select using RANK (can have duplicates)
;WITH cteRank AS
(
    SELECT
        DocGroupViewID,
        Del_Index,
        ID,
        RANK() OVER
            (PARTITION BY DocGroupViewID ORDER BY Del_Index DESC)
        AS RowRank,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (PARTITION BY DocGroupViewID ORDER BY Del_Index DESC)
        AS RowNumber
    FROM @t
)
SELECT *
FROM cteRank
WHERE RowRank = 1

-- select using ROW_NUMBER
;WITH cteRowNumber AS
(
    SELECT
        DocGroupViewID,
        Del_Index,
        ID,
        RANK() OVER
            (PARTITION BY DocGroupViewID ORDER BY Del_Index DESC)
        AS RowRank,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (PARTITION BY DocGroupViewID ORDER BY Del_Index DESC)
        AS RowNumber
    FROM @t
)
SELECT *
FROM cteRowNumber
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

If you have ways to sort out ties, just add it to the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to complicate your query a little bit:

```
select a.docgroupviewid, a.del_index, a.id from table a
    where a.del_index = (select max(b.del_index) from table
        where b.docgroupviewid = a.docgroupviewid)
```