# Find the max value of a column, then group by another column in same table

Tags: php, sql, web-applications

I have a similar problem to [the one solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425240/select-rows-with-maximum-column-value-group-by-another-column), but when I try the solution I think it fails because I have things set up differently..

I have a doc table with...
(unfortunately table cant be edited due to it being an old system)

```
+-------+--------+----------+--------+
| Docid | title  | revision | linkid |
+-------+--------+----------+--------+
| 1     | docone | 1        | 1      |
| 2     | doctwo | 1        | 2      |
| 3     | docone | 2        | 1      |
|4      | docone | 3        | 1      |
+-------+--------+----------+--------+
```

On a page that lists all the documents I want to list only the latest revision of each document.  Doc1 for example is on revision 3 so I want that one and not the other 2.  Doc2 is only on revision 1 so show that one.

Based on the problem in the other post I have writen my query as follows......

```
$query_docs = "
    SELECT `document`.*, doctype.* 
    FROM `document`   
    INNER JOIN doctype    
        ON `document`.iddoctypes = doctype.iddoctypes
    WHERE `document`.revision = (
        SELECT MAX(`document`.revision) AS revision 
        FROM `document`
    )  
    GROUP BY `document`.linkid   
    ORDER BY `document`.doccreation DESC";
```

I have had to link to another table to get the document type (just to make the query harder).

Comment: You might find this easier if you try to get what you want from the document table first, and then worry about adding in the extra detail from doctype.

Comment: is that simply reordering the inner join to after the brackets of the sub query?

Comment: Not really; it's more that you're trying to solve a problem to do with getting some data out of the `document` table. I suggest you concentrate on that, and don't worry about adding extra tables for extra data until you've worked out how to get the data you want out of the `document` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I made a couple minor changes

```
SELECT document.*, doctype.* 
FROM document   
INNER JOIN doctype    
    ON document.iddoctypes = doctype.iddoctypes
WHERE document.revision = (
    SELECT MAX(d1.revision)
    FROM document d1 
    WHERE document.linkid = d1.linkid
)  
ORDER BY document.doccreation DESC
```

Comment: thank you phil but I think I should of metioned that title can change but linkid can not.

Comment: @DanielRobinson I've changed it so that it grabs data based on `linkid` instead of `title`. It should work as expected (I hope!)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  Thank you very much your solution works.  Can I ask something though.  I dont understand the line   from document d1.  Are you changing the name of the doc table to d1?  Is there some info out there I can read as to what you have done?

Comment: Where it says `FROM document d1`, I'm simplying naming the reference to a table. In this instance, whenever I write `d1.revision`, its simply a reference to `document.revision`

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess: I think you have to add `group by title` in your `(select max(...) ...)` subquery.

So the complete statement will be this:

```
$query_docs = "
SELECT `document`.*, doctype.* 
FROM `document`   
INNER JOIN doctype    
    ON `document`.iddoctypes = doctype.iddoctypes
WHERE `document`.revision = (
    SELECT MAX(`document`.revision) AS revision 
    FROM `document`
    --GROUP BY `document`.title
    GROUP BY `document`.linkid
)  
GROUP BY `document`.linkid   
ORDER BY `document`.doccreation DESC";
```

Comment: Unfortunatly the title could change depending on each revision.  The only thing that will always be the same is linkid

Comment: Then my hint is to replace "group by title" with "group by linkid". I've edited my post respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something? This seems completely straightforward...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN (SELECT title,MAX(revision) max_revision FROM my_table GROUP BY title) y
    ON y.title = x.title 
   AND y.max_revision = x.revision;
```