# GROUP BY selecting minimum element in another column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timestamp

Say I had a table like so:

| Timestamp1 | Timestamp2 | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-03-17 20:33:00 | 2015-03-17 20:00:00 | 33 |
| 2015-03-17 20:33:00 | 2015-03-17 21:00:00 | 27 |
| 2015-03-18 19:17:00 | 2015-03-18 20:00:00 | 43 |
| 2015-03-18 19:17:00 | 2015-03-18 19:00:00 | 17 |

Note Diff is calculated as the difference between Timestamp1 and Timestamp2. I would like to use SQL to return the records such that the difference is smallest for records with the same Timestamp1 value.

| Timestamp1 | Timestamp2 | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-03-17 20:33:00 | 2015-03-17 21:00:00 | 27 |
| 2015-03-18 19:17:00 | 2015-03-18 19:00:00 | 17 |

Also, there could be ties, in which case pick randomly (doesn't matter if actually random or hardcoded).

I've tried following something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425240/select-rows-with-maximum-column-value-group-by-another-column) but I'm having trouble with the tie-breaking case where the difference is 30.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions) window function to build an incremental ordering value for each of your differences in your table, then use a `QUALIFY` clause to set that value equal to 1, so that you'll get only the first one row (the minimum difference), ignoring ties.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab 
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Timestamp1 ORDER BY Diff) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Window functions can help, given that you can take the first value with the FIRST_VALUE function

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#first_value

The query could be like this:

```
SELECT 
  FIRST_VALUE(Diff)
    OVER (PARTITION BY Timestamp1 ORDER BY Diff DESC
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS min-diff
  FROM tableA);
```